# Grabbing images from webcam using opencv at specific FPS

Tags: opencv

Is there an OpenCV function that allows me to grab still images at a specific frame rate.  Like I can tell this function to grab 5 images at 10fps, it will take 5 images 0.1 seconds apart exactly.

If not what is a good way to achieve this?  My current attempt is to constantly grab images and only save when time is 0.1 seconds after previous frame but not accurate 10fps

```
afterNextFrame = False
while x < 20:
        now = time.monotonic()

        if now >= nextFrame:
            afterNextFrame = True




        if afterNextFrame == True:
            cameraCap.grab()
            print("\nNow: ", now, "\n")
            _, frame = cameraCap.retrieve()
            # save frame here

            nextFrame += 0.1 # wait 0.1 second for 10 fps
            afterNextFrame = False
```

Comment: It is possible but from where are you trying to read the frames? A video file ? A webcam feed or something else ?

Comment: @ZdaR webcam usb and I want to read 2 webcams at 10 fps simultanously for stereo camera